# Is my formula true for this sum $\sum_{a_n=1}^{t+1}\left(\sum_{a_{n-1}=1}^{a_n}\left(...\left(\sum_{a_0=1}^{a_1}a_0\right)...\right)\right)$?

Tags: summation, products

As you may have read in the title, I'm trying to find out whether my formula is true or not for this strange sum.

Here's my hypothesis:
$$\forall n,t\in \mathbb N^2, \sum_{a_n=1}^{t+1}\left(\sum_{a_{n-1}=1}^{a_n}\left(\sum_{a_{n-2}=1}^{a_{n-1}}\left(...\left(\sum_{a_0=1}^{a_1}a_0\right)...\right)\right)\right) = \prod_{h=1}^{n+2}\frac{t+h}{h}=\frac{(t+n+2)!}{t!(n+2)!}$$

I don't really know how to prove my formula is right. I think my formula is true.
I've tried to prove it by induction, but I don't know how to do it.
Maybe, I am wrong. What's your thinking about it ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: this is the Hockey-stick identity disguised
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: Or even just a combinatorial argument. Writing $a_0=\sum_{a_{-1}=1}^{a_0}1$ and "renaming" $a_k$ to $a_{k+2}$, we see that the sum is equal to the number of $(n+2)$-uples $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n+2})$ with $1\leqslant a_1\leqslant\ldots\leqslant a_{n+2}\leqslant t+1$, which is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) to be $\binom{(t+1)+(n+2)-1}{n+2}$, the same as claimed.